# How are SLS printers able to print multiple colours?

Tags: sls, color

With FFF printers able to manage only a small handful different colours (by using different filaments & extruders), how is it some SLS prints are able to be produced in such a broad range of colours?

Are they sprayed post-production?

Comment: SLS printing only produces monochromatic models. I think you are confusing SLS with another technology.

Comment: Hi, Crollster. It seems like your question needs an update. I have up it on hold for now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Z-corp/3D systems printers lay down what is essentially ink in each layer (only around the perimeters) much like an inkjet printer, dying the powder as the parts are made. This means they can make almost any color at any point in the model. The down size is these models are pretty fragile, at least the last ones that I have handled. This can be helped by dipping them in cyanoacrylate and letting them dry.

As pointed out in the comments, this is not an SLS process, but looks very similar. The printer lays down a binder (clear or colored) on each layer, and is why these models are much more fragile than SLS models, which are very strong.

Here is an example of some prints: http://mcad3dprintingandprototyping.blogspot.com/

Comment: Z-Corp/3D systems are **not SLS** (selective laser sintering) printers.

Comment: This is true, but does answer about how the prints in the original question are multi-colored, the only part missing is the SLS, but I assume that since the process looks like SLS (powder filled build area) that @Crollster may have thought it was SLS. As far as I am aware there is no other method to make these kind of prints.

Comment: I think @Jexoteric has it - I was under the mistaken impression that they were made using the SLS process. Thanks for the clarification!